# Form timer doesn't start

Tags: c#, timer, countdowntimer

So I just started learning C# and using forms.  I have been able to create a digital clock and tinker with this and that, but now I'm trying to make a basic UI for a derpy game and my timer doesn't work.

First - what I'm trying to accomplish:  A simple decrementing timer from 60 seconds (*clock style (mm:ss)).
Second, here's what I have:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int counter = 60;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.Text = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1).ToString("m\\:ss");
    }

    private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter--;
        if (counter == 0)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            label1.Text = counter.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show("Time's Up!!");
        }
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var startTime = DateTime.Now;
        var counter = (TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)).ToString("m\\:ss");
        timer1 = new Timer();
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        timer1.Start();
        label1.Text = counter.ToString();
    }
}
```

Appreciate the feedback and knowledge!

Comment: You might want to swap out that `timer1.Stop()` with `((Timer)sender).Stop()` otherwise you could start two timers within the same second and the first timer will never have Stop called on it.

Comment: You timer will only work once as your counter is globally defined and once it reaches 0 there is no resetting mechanism in place

Comment: Grant, the label1_Click works.  I changed some things so that it started at a different number and when clicked went to the 1:00.  Problem is I don't want to have to click on it.  I want it to start on it's own as soon as the window opens.  Do you know a way to do that??

Scott - Thanks for the intel.

Comment: Hey Groves, that worked like a charm!!  Thanks for the help.  While I have you, let me ask one more question:  I initialized the counter to 60 for the sake of a 60 second countdown.  When it starts the process it goes from the (m\\:ss) view to a simple double digit view.  if I want to progressively go down from say 1:30, I would want it to go down in order (1:29, 1:28, 1:27 and so on.... as opposed to 90, 89, 88...).  Is there a way to do that so that I don't have to initialize a value of 60 to my counter variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the codes that I see, your timer is working but you are not updating it in each count, you are updating when the timer finishes -

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    counter--;
    if (counter == 0)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        label1.Text = counter.ToString(); // *** Look here
        MessageBox.Show("Time's Up!!");
    }
}
```

You should update the timer in each tick, so take the update label code out of the `if` block -

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    counter--;
    label1.Text = counter.ToString(); // should work
    if (counter == 0)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        MessageBox.Show("Time's Up!!");
    }
}
```

and also reset the counter in each cycle -

```
private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var startTime = DateTime.Now;

    var counter = (TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)).ToString("m\\:ss");
    timer1 = new Timer();
    timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    timer1.Interval = 1000;
    timer1.Start();
    label1.Text = counter.ToString();
    this.counter = 60
}
```

> NOTE: I am really not sure if this code will throw any access
>   violation error, due to updating the UI in a different thread or not.
>   If so, then you have to use `async`/`await` or events/delegates to
>   update UI.
>
> Let me know, if this throws error, then I will give you the `async/await` version.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me. I would give progress updates as the time is countdown to show that it is working. For example, if you did this in label, you could do something like the following:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    counter--;
    label1.Text = counter.ToString();
    if (counter == 0)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        MessageBox.Show("Time's Up!!");
    }
}
```

Notice that the `label1.Text = counter.ToString();` line has been moved before the `counter == 0` check, so that it is able to provide feedback for all counter values.

As well, you may accidentally launch several `timer1` instances if you do not keep track of how many you spawn using `new Timer()`. There are various ways to do this, but you could simply check whether `timer1` already exists and `counter == 0` before creating a new instance. You could perform this check as a guard clause (ie. `return` if either of those conditions are matched).

```
private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var startTime = DateTime.Now;
    if (timer1 == null || (timer1 != null && counter == 0)) return;
    counter = (TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)).ToString("m\\:ss");
    timer1 = new Timer();
    timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    timer1.Interval = 1000;
    timer1.Start();
    label1.Text = counter.ToString();
}
```

If you want this countdown to start automatically, you can put this directly into the constructor, or put it into another method and call it from the constructor like so:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    StartCountdown();
}

private void StartCountdown()
{
    var startTime = DateTime.Now;
    /* the rest of your original label1_Click code goes here ... */
}
```